# easiest way to find the HTTP include in a HTTPS throwing security warning?

Tags: asp.net, html, css, security, internet-explorer

I often have to go into other people's work to make modifications for short-term contracts and a lot of times I have to deal with security warnings throwing in IE because something is including HTTP content from maybe an image, or css or whatever, onto a HTTPS secure page.

I was just curious if there is a well known program or service that will scan a URL and come back with exactly what is coming from HTTP instead of HTTPS on a page?

I use fiddler, but for reasons having to do with my own inadequacies, I find the program difficult at times, and am un-able to zero in on the offending content in a timely manner.

Any advice from the true pros?

Comment: I'm sure there's a much more elegant method, but I just view the source and search for http://

Comment: @DoozerBlake: This *mostly* works - unless your JS dynamically loads resources, or unless there's no `base` tag, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Fiddler:

In `main menu > Tools > Fiddler options`, tab `HTTPS`, uncheck `Capture HTTPS CONNECTs`. Then, in `main menu > Rules`, check `Hide HTTPS CONNECTs`.

This way, the only thing you'll see in your Fiddler capture will be the HTTP requests and responses (without the HTTPS requests or CONNECTs getting in the way).

Answer (score 2):

I would load up the page in Firefox and use Firebug's Net panel to examine all the resources that the page loads.

Comment: Note that this could miss e.g. resources loaded within conditional comments (which are IE-specific).

Answer (score 2):

There's no 'set in stone' way as far as I know, but the easiest way I know of is to either use a tool such as Opera Dragonfly or Chrome's Web Inspector, view the 'Network' tab and see where the resources are being loaded from. You can sometimes (depending on what you use) order this alphabetically and you will clearly see between `http://` and `https://`.

Also as already mentioned, you could just search the source for `http://`.